# C program causes segmentation fault in Linux command line but exits normally in gdb

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gdb

I wrote the following C program to print out each byte of an integer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
union bytes
{   int number;
    char bytes[sizeof(int)];
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   for (int i=1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        int* x;
        *x = atoi(argv[i]);
        union bytes bytes_of_x;
        bytes_of_x.number = *x;
        for (int j=0; j < sizeof(int); j++)
        {
            unsigned char b = *((unsigned char*)x + j);
            bytes_of_x.bytes[j] = b;
        }
        for (int k=0; k < sizeof(int); k++)
        {
            printf("Byte %d = %x\n", k+1, bytes_of_x.bytes[k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It compiled fine with no warnings, but when I ran it on the command line (using ./progname integer) it returned a segmentation fault.

I ran the program in gdb with several different inputs but each time it exited normally.

How should I go about identifying the source of the segmentation fault since gdb does not identify any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It compiled fine with no warnings

You need to turn on *additional* warnings, or you need a better compiler.

Using GCC 8.3.0:

```
gcc -g t.c -Wall
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:12:12: warning: ‘x’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         *x = atoi(argv[i]);
         ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

gcc -g t.c -Wall -Wextra
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:15:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int j=0; j < sizeof(int); j++)
                         ^
t.c:20:25: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wsign-compare]
         for (int k=0; k < sizeof(int); k++)
                         ^
t.c:12:12: warning: ‘x’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         *x = atoi(argv[i]);
         ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As other answers have already said, you are writing through an uninitialized pointer, which results in undefined behavior. UB means: anything can happen, including the program appearing to work on one machine, but not another, or working under GDB and not working outside of GDB, or vice versa.

> How should I go about identifying the source of the segmentation fault since gdb does not identify any errors?

You can use GDB for post-mortem debugging:

```
# Set core dump size to be unlimited
ulimit -c unlimited

# Generate a core dump
./a.out 42
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

gdb a.out core    # now use GDB to debug the crash.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have not allocated any memory to `x`. This variable is a pointer and yet you use it without it having been assigned any valid memory to use.

You need to `malloc` memory for `x` like this:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and remember to `free` it afterwards, like this:

```
free(x);
```

at the end of each `for` loop iteration.

However, I question the need to actually declare `x` this way to begin with. Why not just assign the `argv[i]` argument to an `int` variable declared on the stack first & then initialize a second variable to point to it, like this:

```
int y = atoi(argv[i]);
int *x = &y;
```

Also, you say your program *"compiled fine with no warnings"*. That indicates to me that you haven't compiled your code with at least *some* basic compilation flags that would've warned you about `x` being uninitialized. For example, using `gcc`:

```
gcc -Wall program.c
```

would've caught this error easily, and

```
gcc -Wall -Werror program.c
```

would've prevented the compilation "succeeding" altogether.

Please have a read of your compiler's manual pages to learn more about compilation flags that will save you time & trouble.

Also: Another useful tool to look into is [valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) -- which does a brilliant job at detecting uninitialized variables, memory leaks and more.